# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am facing with an error which is unclear for me.
I am able to see the data to edit but everytime it is coming an error like this.
I have tried to catch error but I am not getting no where it is coming from:
Every console.log works as excepted.
I think the problem it is somewhere the data when load for first time are null.
And this is only coming if I try to show the second `ngFor` because If I let only the first than it is working everything fine but not showing then the `arrays of comments the second *ngFor`.

`RROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (PostsListComponent.html:20)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]`

I am getting the data something like this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async; trackBy:trackByFunction">
    <td class="title">{{post.title}}</td>
    <td class="dateTime">{{post.body}}</td>
    <div *ngFor="let comment of (groupedComments$ | async)[post.id]; trackBy:trackByFunction">
      <div>
      <td *ngIf="!isEditable(comment)" class="comment">{{comment.name}}</td>
      <textarea class="comment" *ngIf="isEditable(comment)" [(ngModel)]="editableComment.name"></textarea>
      <td *ngIf="!isEditable(comment)"class="comment">{{comment?.body}}</td>
      <textarea class="comment" *ngIf="isEditable(comment)" [(ngModel)]="editableComment.body"></textarea>

      <td class="comment" *ngIf="comment.email === 'Just@do.it' && comment.body.length < 200">
        {{comment.email}}
        <button  *ngIf="!isEditable(comment)" (click)="deleteComment(comment.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <button *ngIf="!isEditable(comment)" (click)="editComment(comment)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Edit</button>
        <button *ngIf="isEditable(comment)" (click)="update(comment)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Update</button>
        <button *ngIf="isEditable(comment)" (click)="cancel()" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 10px">Cancel</button>
      </td>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tr>
```

The `TS` file.

```
posts$: Observable<Post[]>;
  comments$: Observable<Comment[]>;
  groupedComments$: Observable<CommentGroup>;
  editableComment = emptyComment();

  constructor(private postsService: PostService,
              private commentsService: CommentService,
              private confirmationDialogService: ConfirmationDialogService) {
    this.getAllData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  getAllData() {
    this.posts$ =  this.postsService.getPostsList();
    this.comments$ = this.commentsService.getCommentsList();
    this.groupedComments$ = this.comments$.pipe(
      map(comments => lodash.groupBy(comments, 'postId')),
    );
  }
```

And this are my services.

```
export class PostService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/posts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getPostsList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
export class CommentService {
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/comments';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getComment(id: number): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
}

getCommentsList(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the code inside the <td> with an ngContainer: <ng-container *ngIf="!!posts>...</ng-container>

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Which td ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the tr. <tr><ng-container> list of TD </ng-container></tr>

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Why you write like this `*ngIf="!!posts"` where my `posts` it is declared like `posts$` ?
And I have changed but thee same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupedComments$ | async` is `null` before receiving http response, that's why.

Comment: How to fix that ?

Comment: A way to do it is wrapping ngFor by a ngIf like this: <ng-container *ngIf="groupedComments$ | async as groupedComments"><div ngFor="let comment of groupedComments[...]">...</div></ng-container>

Comment: @ZhuniqiA implement a null check in html, as suggested in the comments to your question.

Comment: @htn You are right I didn't know that I can do this with `ng-container` and this worked.
@AnandBhushan I was able to fix this thanks to @htn.

Comment: @htn I want you to ask something else if you have time ?